# Unable to approve user registrations via email link

Tags: user

Since the latest update of Joomla I can no longer approve a user via the link in the registration approval email.

> As of 3.8.13, Joomla is securing the process on approving an user after an email notification by requesting the administrator, who is going to approve the request, to login into the frontend. After the administrator logged in, they are redirected to the activation URL and the account is activated.

However this does not work. I click the link and get the message:

***Please log in to confirm that you are authorised to activate new accounts.***

When I then log in as Super User I get the message: 
***You are not authorised to view this resource*** 
and the user remains unapproved.

Any suggestions as to how to get around this issue?

Comment: I'd suggest posting an issue on the [Joomla Issue Tracker](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues as it may be a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have discovered my issue. It appears to be due to ACL (access level) for the login menu item. It has to be public.

I followed the steps for the first answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883387/joomla-3-4-8-logged-in-users-seeing-error-you-are-not-authorised-to-view-this-re)  and now it works perfectly.